# Convenient way to use LIKE case sensivity in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, optimization, sql-like

As I see LIKE operator can optimize query if I switch PRAGMA case_sensitive_like=ON. I measured, it really worked, queries "LIKE someth%" becomes ten times faster on a compartively large binary indexed tables.
But the problem is that my library implemented as an add-on to my application, it maintains its own tables with any db it is connected. So the problems are

- I can not read *case_sensitive_like* since it is only supported to be set, not read. So I can not temporarily read the state and return it after the query,
- As an addon that should obey the main functionality of the db, I should not change the setting to my need for good since it can affect other routines.
- As I see there's no Like(case-sensitive) internal equivalent for me to call optimizid query directly. For example use LIKECASESENSITIVE instead of LIKE
- I can call sqlite3_create_function, but I don't know whether or not I can call LIKE(CASE SENSITIVE) internally.

Answer (score 6):

> I can not read `case_sensitive_like`
>   since it is only supported to be set,
>   not read. So I can not temporarily
>   read the state and return it after the
>   query

You can get the state of `case_sensitive_like` with a query like this one:

```
select case when 'a' like 'A' then 0 else 1 end
```

which will return `1` if `case_sensitive_like = ON` and `0` if it's `OFF`.